# How to prevent Magento removing grouped items

Tags: php, magento, observers

I have successfully created a grouped product which contains 4 products and all is working fine. However, one of the items is a free item, only available when purchasing the grouped product. My problem is, when going to the basket, I can edit it and remove some of the items. Is there a way to remove the free item if someone edits a grouped product from the basket and throw a message, is this possible?

I am using Magento v1.3.2.4

**UPDATE:**

I am still having issues! Using Marius' advice, I have created a custom module called FreePins with the following code in app/etc/modules/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <test_FreePins>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </test_FreePins>
    </modules>
</config>
```

I have created and added the following in app/code/local/test/FreePins/etc/config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <test_FreePins>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </test_FreePins>
    </modules>
    <global>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
                <sales_quote_remove_item>
                    <observers>
                        <test_FreePins>
                                <class>test_FreePins/observer</class>
                                <method>removeFreeItems</method>
                        </test_FreePins>
                    </observers>
                </sales_quote_remove_item>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Finally, I have the following in  my Observer class in app/code/local/test/FreePins/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php

class test_FreePins {

    public function removeFreeItems($observer) {
        $quoteItem = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
        $productId = $quoteItem->getProductId();

        print_r($productId);

        if($productId != 238 || $productId != 22 || $productId != 4) {
            return $this;
        }
    }

}

?>
```

I'm not entirely sure if this correct, as I cannot remove items from my basket once added. If I comment out the Frontend tags in the module config, the site works, but my function does not run, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an observer for the event `sales_quote_remove_item`. In that check if the item removed is part of a grouped product. If it is, remove the free product also.
Something like this (replace `[module]` with your module name):
in `config.xml` of your module add this inside the `<frontend>` tag.

```
<events>
    <sales_quote_remove_item>
       <observers>
           <[module]>
               <class>[module]/observer</class>
                   <method>removeFreeItems</method>
           </[module]
       </observers>
    </sales_quote_remove_item>
</events>
```

In your observer class add this method:

```
public function removeFreeItems($observer){
   $quoteItem = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
   $productId = $quoteItem->getProductId();
   if (the $productId is not part of the grouped product){//add logic here
        return $this;//stop here
   }
   foreach ($quoteItem->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item){
       if ($item is free){//add your logic here
           $item->isDeleted(true);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Marius. I'm not entirely sure how to make a module, but I found [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method) , so once I have it setup, I will give your code a try and post back

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using "Shopping Cart Price Rule". However if you use this kind of approach the item will be displayed with the full price in the cart and a discount will be applied. If you can live with that, here is how to do that:

1. Since you cant relay rules on product ids we need to create a new hidden category(A category that is not used in the navigation or deactivated), where you add the bundle product
2. Create another hidden category where you add the item that should be for free
3. Create a new "Shopping Cart Price Rule" with no coupon and a high priority (0 is the highest)
4. As condition add "Product Attribute Combination" and then select "Product Attribute->Category"
5. As Category use the previously created category with your bundle
6. On the "Actions" Tab select "Percent of product price discount" and set the discount amount to "100"
7. On the same tab under "Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)" select again "Product Attribute Combination" and then select "Product Attribute->Category" but now choose the category with the "free item".
8. Your done as soon as you add you bundle the the cart, a discount will be applied and displayed.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Fantus, but I have already looked at this and decided against it.